# Docker save image to tar through remote API

Tags: docker

I would like to export an image to a tar file, and I'm looking at the [Docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) command. I can't seem to find it in the [remote API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.20/) though.

I see other commands in the remote API that supports tar streams in both the request and the response, so it seems like it should be possible.

Is this not supported, or am I missing something?

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: Fixed first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know Ruby, you can try the gem *docker-api*:

```
# Export a single Docker Image to a file
# Docker command for reference: docker save <IMAGE.ID> my_export.tar
image.save('my_export.tar')
# => Docker::Image { :id => 66b712aef, :connection => Docker::Connection { :url => tcp://localhost, :options => {:port=>2375} } }
```

You can also use it to create any image from a tar file:

```
# Create an image from a tar file.
# Docker command for reference: docker build - < docker_image.tar
Docker::Image.build_from_tar(File.open('docker_image.tar', 'r'))
# => Docker::Image { :id => 1266dc19e, :connection => Docker::Connection { :url => tcp://localhost, :options => {:port=>2375} } }
```

Refer to:

1. readme: [swipely/docker-api](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api)

Comment: So, after looking through the source code of the gem docker-api, it uses [GET /images/image_id/get][2] which seems to do the same as docker save, only over REST. [2]: https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.20/#get-a-tarball-containing-all-images-in-a-repository

Comment: well, your edit references the /containers/(id)/export which is different from /images/(id)/get.